# jq: how to change array value conditionally

Tags: json, edit, jq

A am new at json and jq. I searched internet but could not find solution for my problem.
I have a json file with each object containing array. I need to change some of array elements conditionally: if contact_type = email and value like "yahoo.com" replace "yahoo.com" with "hotmail.com".
My file:

```
[  
    {
        "name": "fluffy",
        "type": "cat",
        "contact_info": [
             {
                 "contact_type": "phone",
                 "value": "123-456-6789"
             },
             {
                 "contact_type": "email",
                 "value": "fluffy_mean_cat@gmail.com"
             }
        ]
    },
    {
         "name": "breeze",
         "type": "dog",
         "contact_info": [
             {
                  "contact_type": "phone",
                  "value": "125-856-6789"
             },
             {
                  "contact_type": "email",
                  "value": "breeze@yahoo.com"
             }
         ]
    }
]
```

Resulting file has to look like this:

```
[
    {
         "name": "fluffy",
         "type": "cat",
         "contact_info": [
             {
                  "contact_type": "phone",
                  "value": "123-456-6789"
             },
             {
                  "contact_type": "email",
                  "value": "fluffy_mean_cat@gmail.com"
             }
         ]
    },
    {
         "name": "breeze",
         "type": "dog",
         "contact_info": [
             {
                  "contact_type": "phone",
                  "value": "125-856-6789"
             },
             {
                  "contact_type": "email",
                  "value": "breeze@hotmail.com"
             }
         ]
    }
]
```

Please help.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a look at https://jsonnet.org/ to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of many possible solutions:

```
walk( if type == "object"
        and .contact_type == "email"
        and (.value | index("yahoo.com"))
      then .value |= sub("yahoo.com"; "hotmail.com")
      else . end )
```

### Direct approach

```
def update:
  if .contact_type == "email"
     and (.value | index("yahoo.com"))
  then .value |= sub("yahoo.com"; "hotmail.com")
  else . 
  end ;

map( if .contact_info 
     then .contact_info |= map(update)
     else .
     end )
```

### `else .`

After the release of jq 1.6, a change was made allowing the `else .` to be dropped.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution in *jq 1.5*? Since the `walk(f)` function is not in *jq 1.5*.

Comment: Yes, but you can just copy-and-paste the def of `walk`. Simply google: jq def walk